# Retagging a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, tags

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997199/how-to-improve-the-following-sql-select-date-in-rdb) of mine related to Oracle RDB retagged. A high rep user removed my [oracle-rdb](/questions/tagged/oracle-rdb) tag and replaced it with an [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) tag. Later in the comments, he mentioned that he hadn't heard of Oracle RDB and thought that Oracle RDB 7 was just the version before Oracle 8.

My question doesn't really have anything to do with Oracle and really is an RDB question as the two have different syntax/are different systems. Should the tag change be reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Educate us -- what is Oracle RDB?

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/rdb/index.html

Why is there only one question (yours) ever tagged this in the entire history of Stack Overflow?

How does it relate to the Oracle database we all know <s>and love</s>?

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/index.htm

Comment: Thanks Jeff...RDB was bought by Oracle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Rdb and is a different product, but interesting about the sharing between the two. seems obvious now, but the tag should have been RDB...although that only has (3) references so I've made up 20% of the questions anyway...I guess this highlights that RDB either a) isn't used much b) isn't used much by SO users c) is only used in special cases (perhaps legacy) or d) that RDB is generally awesome and has no misunderstandings or learning curve thus requiring no questions

Comment: another point while looking at the tags is that the tag 'rdb' is easily confused with the rag 'rdbms'...I guess the similar names/acronyns and not widespread use of RDB makes it an annoying case...

Comment: Just realised I had deleted my other rdb question a few days ago, which is why it was the only one tagged like that...thanks Shog9 for cleaning that up

Comment: Oracle Rdb: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Rdb "Oracle is still ... developing this product in 2008 ... runs on OpenVMS for VAX, Alpha and IA-64 (Itanium)."